# "Review" link on StackExchange bar not listed under privileges

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, stack-exchange, privileges

It appears the "review" link on the main StackExchange bar doesn't show up until you have 125 reputation points. Shouldn't that be listed as a privilege on the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down)?

I just noticed upon posting a bounty, when I lost my "review" link.

Comment: it ties into the "vote down" priv, I am not opposed to adding a separate one

Comment: I think it would encourage more user interaction if they knew they had earned a new privilege, and didn't just stumble upon it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It is now.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66276/12)