# The review page returns a "page not found" error

Tags: support, review

When browsing the [badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges), I found some badges' description refer to [reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review).
Somehow I get page not found error when trying to access [reviewing page](https://stackoverflow.com/review). Is it just me or is it a Stack Overflow bug?

Comment: I can get there right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it may be that with only `1` reputation, you are not eligible to review posts, just yet.

Comment: Makes sense. But all I got is a "page not found" page. Also can not upload screenshot of it due to low reputation. IMO a "You don't have enough reputation to review" page would be nice if reputation is the case.

Comment: I don't disagree with that at all, especially since you can come across links to that page in ways such as you did. (Just for information's sake; the Review page also works fine for me, so there's nothing wrong with it. It just confusingly shows a 404 for users who can't access it)

Comment: Andrew, sorry for the confusion. Actually there is no mention of 404 of that page. It's just my first impression: the page is missing, there is a 404 error.The page I got reads: Page Not Found We couldn't find the page you requested. We did, however, find this program.

    Try searching for similar questions
    Browse recent questions
    Browse popular tags

If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us.

Comment: Yes, @wang, that is the 404 page for the website.

Comment: Try this (invalid) link for example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/invalidPage

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had noticed this too, you don't actually get the "review" page or privilege until you hit 125 rep, I only noticed it once I started reviewing, and lost it, by giving out a bounty.

- ["Review" link on StackExchange bar not listed under privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113144/review-link-on-stackexchange-bar-not-listed-under-privileges)